# Open hyperlink in new tab , Everything should be written in HREF attribute value only

Tags: javascript, html

I have a  limitation where one can use only href attribute in anchor  tag inorder to open a URl in a new tab.

ALL THE STUFF SHOULD BE WRITTEN IN "HREF" ATTRIBUTE VALUE ONLY, INORDER TO OPEN URL IN NEW TAB.

Is it possible to open the URL in a new tab with the mentioned limitation?

Comment: Seems a very strange limitation, rather than using the standard `target="_blank"`

Comment: Why are you shouting (caps lock on)? We understood the question after the first statement itself.

Comment: Just to give a clarity if i sound something confusing.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com/');">…</a>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `<a href="http://www.test.com" target="_blank" /> Test </a>` is a better answer.

You're using Javascript to replicate native HTML syntax & behaviour - which can be turned off, thus making your link not work at all?